# Java: Проблема с регистром в String

Tags: java, строки

Есть слово записанное с переменную `String` (допустим `Сметана`).

Пользователь вводит его и должен его найти.

```
int a = text.indexOf(search);
```

И дело в том, что если в `search` слово `Сметана` написана с маленькой буквы (а в тексте с большой), переменная `а` по умолчанию будет равна -1.

Как не учитывать регистр?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом String.toLowerCase(String), к примеру:

```
int a = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: или `text.toUpperCase()`

Comment: лучше ещё использовать метод .trim() (убирает лишние пробелы в начале и в конце строки), т.к. пользователь может случайно их поставить

Answer (score 0):

Для простого поиска достаточно использовать стандартные методы String.
Например, привести строки к верхнему или нижнему регистру.

Цитата из ответа автора [pkamozin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4089/pkamozin):

> `int a = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase());`

Также можно использовать [регулярные выражения](https://habrahabr.ru/post/260773/) для более сложной обработки строк в плане поиска и работы с выражениями/подстроками.